# GRASS GIS: r.diversity

Tags: grass

I lauched the script r.diveristy.py in GRASS GIS 6.4.3 from launch script option in file menu. After that the r.diversity GUI appeared in which I gave the input and the output file name and then run. The  following error message  is displayed:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin\python.exe: can't open file
'r.diversity.py': [Errno 2] No such File or directory.
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

GRASS GIS 6.4.3 is rather old and there were problems with running Python scripts on MS Windows (r.diversity is a Python script). Install the latest release (currently 7.0.4) and install the r.diversity module from Addons again. There was a lot of improvements regarding Python scripts in the 7.0 series.